# Passing a list item as string (or using an alternative)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a reddit bot that converts some html (specifically, tables) to markdown.

Assuming `soup` is a `BeautifulSoup` object of a page I've fetched, here is my code:

```
myTable = soup.find('div', id='damage-chart-panel').findAll('tr')
text = list()
for tr in myTable:
    text.append(tr.findAll('td'))
    for item in text: #a list item in 'text'
        tags = '(<[^>]+>)' #pattern for <anything enclosed in these things>
        re.sub(tags, '|', item) #because markdown table cols are separated by |
print text
```

When I run this, I get the error `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. I realize this is happening because I'm passing a list item to `re.sub()`. I've been looking for a solution for a while now but I still can't wrap my head around it. How can I pass the list item as a string?

Also: I've considered just letting `text` be a string, but the thing is I am supposed to append newlines, that is, `\n` preceded by two spaces, at the end of every row and I'm not sure how to do that without making it a list/array (?). Any advice on how I would go about carrying out my task?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the elements to string and use `str.join()`:

```
text.append('\n'.join([str(cell) for cell in tr.find_all('td')]))
```

or you could use `list.extend()`:

```
text.extend(map(str, tr.find_all('td')))
```

Comment: Thank you! However I am still missing two key aspects: I only need `\n` at the end of every **row**, but I also need every `<td>` tag replaced with `|` (hence the regex pattern in the code I have). Is there any way I can manipulate `join()` to do this?

Comment: @Xozzo: If you are trying to produce a CSV, use the `csv` module (set the delimiter to `|`), and pass in `csvwriter.writerow([cell.text() for cell in tr.find_all('td')])` instead; that'll write pipe-separated *cell contents* (per row) to your file.